# Visual Studio WPF Project build Output path

Tags: wpf, build, visual-studio-2012

I have a Solution that contain 3 projects.
1 Windows application and 2 class library.

Folder structure tree on my disc is as following:
\projects\CurrentProject\test\
\projects\CurrentProject\build\

The solution files are located under:
/projects/CurrentProject/

All 3 projects are located at \projects\CurrentProject\test\

I need all the **build outputs** of all projects (1.exe and 2 dlls) to be under \projects\CurrentProject\build\ ...
So on each project, i go to "project properties", select on both debug/release the output path to be: "....\build", but still after doing so, i have files on /obj of the class library projects.

Why is this ?

Thanks

Comment: The obj folder is not the output folder, it is an intermediate folder.

Comment: can you reference me to good article that explain what is the intermediate folder ? what files are in it, when do they get there, their meaning etc.. Thanks ! could find good one for newbies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move your obj folder elsewhere your can customize your build configuration using the [`BaseIntermediateOutputPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) property in the project file (the `.csproj` file).

To do it:

1. Open the `.csproj file` in a text editor (the `.csproj` file is an XML file)
2. Edit the value of the element BaseIntermediateOutputPath or add it in the desired `PropertyGroup`. (The line to modify or to add looks like `<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\build\obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>`)
3. Save the file
4. Reopen your project in Visual Studio.